# Resetting an object to zero?

Tags: java, infinite-loop

Hi guys I know this is a weird question but can an object return to being `zero`? I'm asking because I have a huge design flaw with a basic GUI that i'm running where if I answer what I wanted on a menu it would continue to use the same old answer.

To get around that I would ask again on the lower part but then I ran into a worse problem..it kept on asking. I feel trapped tbh and I can't find anyway inside my programming book to `reset` or get around this.

```
Object[] menuPossibilities = {"Create a New Account", "Deposit", "Withdraw", "Display Balance", "Exit"};

Object menuValues = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please pick an option from this menu: ",
            "input", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, menuPossibilities, menuPossibilities [0]);
while (!menuValues.equals("Exit")){

    Bank newBank = new Bank();
    // Bank newBank1 = new Bank();
    // Bank newBank2 = new Bank(); Do the same thing as below but switch out
    // bank1 and bank2 as a substitute.
    ArrayList<BankAccount> bankList = newBank.getBankAccounts();

        if (menuValues.equals("Create a New Account")){

            newBank.openAccount();
        }

        else if (menuValues.equals("Deposit")){
            newBank.deposit();
        }
        else if (menuValues.equals("Withdraw")){
            newBank.withdraw();
        }
        else if (menuValues.equals("Display Balace")){
            newBank.deposit();
        }
        else if (menuValues.equals("Exit")){
            System.out.println("Thank you for using our service.");
        }

        Object menuValuesTWO = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Since you did not pick 5 please pick another option: ",
                    "input", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, menuPossibilities, menuPossibilities [0]);

}
```

The above is the code I have in case I wasn't very clear. But basically If I take out the `menuvalueTWO` and hit the create bank account then it'll loop back around and say `"So wanna make another bank account?"`.

Comment: Shouldn't menuValuesTWO  be menuValues since you are looping the while on that?

Answer (score 0):

> ... can an object return to being zero?

Not unless some method explicitly sets it to zero.

In cases like this the problem is typically something else; for example, that you are actually looking at *different objects*.

In your example, it looks like you have made some mistakes in the way that you have modeled and/or implemented operations like `openAccount`, `deposit` and `withdraw`.  I would expect:

- `openAccount()` should return the `BankAcount` it created, and also add it to the Bank's bank account list.
- `deposit()` should be an operation on a `BankAccount` and should take a parameter saying how much to deposit.
- `withdraw()` should be an operation on a `BankAccount` and should take a parameter saying how much to withdraw.

And so on.

(Alternatively, if `deposit` and `withdraw` are operations on the `Bank` object, then they need another parameter - an account number? - to say which account to operate on.)

Answer (score 0):

```
Object menuValuesTWO = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Since you did not pick 5 please pick another option: ",
                    "input", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, menuPossibilities, menuPossibilities [0]);
```

should be

```
menuValues = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Since you did not pick 5 please pick another option: ",
                    "input", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, menuPossibilities, menuPossibilities [0]);
```

I can't validate the change as I cannot run your code. But as @Stephen C suggested you must use the same object that you are looping on.

Comment: Maybe it's because of how I did it the time before but Shire's code is working. I imagine that I just misspelled or missed a tiny bit of synthax or something..I honestly can't say why. Anyways thank you for your help. I guess this is just a case of "ask the question again" if you want a different answer.